# Is it possible to disable Telegram's standard text input while buttons are available?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot that provides button choices to the user. I'd like to ensure the user chooses from one of the buttons, rather than sending a custom text message or sticker or whatever. Is there some way to do this? As far as I can tell from the docs I can't.

Comment: You are correct. It is impossible to deprive user of entering and sending arbitrary text.

Comment: You can't disable the text input as this is core functionality of the app. (Inline) Keyboards can be used with some additional logic that will ask the user to press one of the buttons if a text message is received. If the bot has the power, it could delete any text messages when a button is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no! I am going to handle this by getting the bot to ignore any text input until the user selects one of the button options.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for the complete disabling of the keyboard. but so far, I'm making the bot tell the user to choose only from the buttons (better than ignoring random input IMHO).

Comment: Yes, a good addendum on usability if you take my approach!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. You cannot hide the keyboard. Assuming you are using `python-telegram-bot` module for your bot, here is an example to ignore the users' random input within a conversation, which is probably where you encountered the problem:

(version is python-telegram-bot==20.7)

```
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "ANSWER ME?!.",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            [["my", "allowed", "buttons"]], one_time_keyboard=True
        ),
    )


async def handle_first_question(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    # handle allowed input
    print(update.message.text)

    # go to next state, everything went smoothly
    return SECOND_STATE


async def handle_wrong_input(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    # ask user to press buttons, show buttons again
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "I didn't understand that. Please use buttons.",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            [["my", "allowed", "button", "values"]], one_time_keyboard=True
        ),
    )
    # stay in first state until user gave correct answer
    return FIRST_STATE


survey_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
    states={
        FIRST_STATE: [
            # handler for allowed values
            MessageHandler(
                # except only valid keys
                filters.Regex("^(my|allowed|button|values)$"),
                handle_first_question,
            ),
            # handler that handles invalid replies and catches all inputs that were not caught before
            MessageHandler(filters.ALL, handle_wrong_input),
        ],
        SECOND_STATE: [...],
    },
)
```

Important is the regex filter that filters button values followed by the handler that accept all other inputs. You need this for each state in the conversation handler.